# Create LINQ in table that has many2many relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have many2many ralationship created by Entity Framework.

I try to retrive data from table that has many2many relation.

Here the scheme:

[image]

Here is Linq I created:

```
var inspArchive = context
    .Set<InspectionArchive>()
    .Where(x => x.CustomerId == clientId && x.InspectionDomainId == domainId)
    .Select(x=>x);
```

The LINQ get records from inspectionArchives table Where conditions are met.

In the LINQ above I need to include one more condition, take into consideration the Id of InspectionAuthoreties table.

How can I change the LINQ above to take into consideration the Id of InspectionAuthoreties table.

Comment: as its many to many so be specific what you want? after the "InspectionArchive"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that `InspectionArchive` entity has a collection navigation property of type `InspectionAuthority`, then you can do this:

```
int inspectionAuthId=3;
var inspArchive = context.Set<InspectionArchive>()
                         .Where(x => x.CustomerId == clientId 
                                    && x.InspectionDomainId == domainId
                                    && x.InspectionAuthorities.Any(ia=>ia.Id==inspectionAuthId));
                       //.Select(x=>x); you don't need this select
```

Another solution could be using query notation:

```
int inspectionAuthId=3;
var inspArchive = from ia in context.Set<InspectionArchive>()
                  from i in ia.InspectionAuthorities
                  where  ai.CustomerId == clientId 
                         && ai.InspectionDomainId == domainId
                         && i.Id==inspectionAuthId
                  select ia;
```

Comment: Why I don't need select?

Comment: Because you're projecting the same entity, in the second solution is mandatory due to the syntax of query notation.

Answer (score 1):

Build your query with `from` the `InspectionAuthoreties inspectionArchives`.

Your where will be based on

```
 x => x.InspectionAuthoreties.CustomerId
```

Join on both sides and return the InspectionArchive part of the result